# forEach not hitting last index's

Tags: angularjs, foreach, angularjs-directive, promise, angularjs-scope

Hello I'm looping through an array within my Angular Controller and passing a Promise function to each value, then dynamically creating a $scope module for each one labeled "$scope['index_0]" for example.

```
        app.controller('arrCtrl', function($scope, dataService){
            var catList = <%-JSON.stringify(myCats)%>;
            var sequence = Promise.resolve();
            catList.forEach(function(catObj, index){
                sequence = sequence.then(function(){
                    return dataService.getItemsByCategory(catObj._id);
                }).then(function(result){
                    //Create and set scope module to Items array
                    $scope['items_'+index] = result;
                }).catch(function(err){//catch any error
                    console.log(err + ' failed to load!');
                });
            });
            console.log("Controller loaded");
        });
```

Everything works well until I reach the last index. Although the last iteration's $scope is recognized within the controller, it's not recognized when I display it.

```
 <p ng-repeat="item in items_2">{{item.Name}}</p>
```

$scope['item_2'] is my last index and the above example will not display.

Comment: Creating a fiddle or plunker for the problem can help batter solving the problem

Comment: `["item_2"]` or `["items_2"]`?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 ["items_2"]